# Smoke not rendering in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I made a new Blender file and added Quick Smoke to the default cube. I changed the renderer from Eevee to Cycles and switched to GPU Compute. When I render, all I see is the cube; the smoke doesn't appear. I've tried switching the cache type to Final and rebaking the sim and nothing changes. When I save the file and close and re-open Blender, nothing changes, and if I rebake after that, nothing changes.

Viewport:
[image]
[image]

Render:
[image]

I should note that while I am on 2.9 alpha, this happens in 2.82 and 2.83 beta as well.

Before this gets marked as a duplicate, I've tried everything listed on other questions on this site and on Google that I could find.

Comment: Make sure the cube is disabled from being rendered (camera icon) and your domain has a proper shader (eg. a principled volume) applied. Also, don't forget to bake the sim.

Comment: If i see it correctly you are using 2.9 .. thats currently in Alpa state... Maybe try a Stable version.

Comment: @J.Doe Edited; it happens in 2.82 stable and 2.83 beta as well.

Comment: Here is my quick take on it: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/JYajA7v5/  Renders fine on 2.8x... Can you test it?

Comment: @brockmann That file renders fine for me: https://imgur.com/9GrkCjR. Let me try using Modular instead of Final in my file.

Comment: @brockmann Using Modular seems to have fixed this issue. Interesting. Perhaps there was something else along the line that I did as well, but as far as I can tell, Modular bake made the difference.

Comment: Setting the cache type to 'Modular' solves that issue? I don't believe that's true. Setting it to *Replay* and *Final* working here too. Can you share your file?

Comment: @brockmann Absolutely; this is the file where I first noticed the issue: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hWYk3LQQI8MmZeyi52qZJji0c50tG718/view (it's a .zip because I have textures and reference images and I don't know if not including them would prevent the .blend from working)

Comment: @brockmann For just the cube file, here's a link to mine: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-Ek9Lmmc0JvgBnM-mwFV2yDaFqCKeBjC/view

Comment: Your are right, but I think that's a bug and should be reported...

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you didn't disable render for the domain.
[image]